# Виджет (php twig)

Tags: php, twig, виджет

По немного познаю php.

У меня есть проект он написан на php + шаблонизатор twig.

Движок полностью самописный, в нем есть модуль поддержки, так вот модуль выдает список чата на странице, и в попапе (можно прочитать чат, написать ответ отправить смс).

Хотел узнать как реализовать вывод подобной информации через код виджет, а точнее его код, как например в prestashop.

То есть есть отдельный вид за который отвечает этот виджет, и вставив например код этого виджета у меня в этой области на странице появиться вывод информации в виде который собственно реализован.

Основной вопрос как транслировать вид, короткими участками кода (виджетом)

Возможно вопрос водянистый но буду рад любой помощи и советам в этой теме!

(я думаю можно заинклудить наверное просто определенный вид туда куда это нужно) но наверняка есть профессиональное решение